# Error in installing cURL on a Linux Machine

Tags: linux, curl

IGNORE THIS ENTIRE THING, LEAVING HERE FOR CONTEXT, SEE QUESTION AT VERY END.

This is a rather weird situation I've put myself in. I installed [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) and everything appears to be working, except for the code itself. If I try

```
man curl_easy_init
```

the man page for the function comes up. I try

```
curl -V
```

and

```
curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

comes up, which implies that I installed it right. I even went to /usr/include and the curl/curl.h file was there. Now when I try an incredibly simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL * curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl)
  {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

On compiling, I get the errors these errors:

```
gcc -Wall test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
 test.c:7:12: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
/tmp/ccT4IJ5R.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
test.c:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
test.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
test.c:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Even though I can do a man page request on any of these functions, it can't find them properly. This means that the curl.h file wasn't linked properly, or something like that. How badly did I screw up installing the curl library?

EDIT: FOUND ANSWER, NEW QUESTION

After I took the time to write this all out, I found a similar question with the answer of "include -lcurl" and my programs compile. Why is this necessary when I already include the header file curl/curl.h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this necessary when I already include the header file curl/curl.h?

The header file `curl.h` tells compiler the prototypes and other informations about functions in curl library, and `-lcurl` tells linker where to look for the definition of those functions.